# LinkedList with for loop and Scanner

Tags: java

I'm trying to practice LinkedList. Simple code, the user enters x number of integers and the program outputs them on the screen. When I put the length of the LinkedList I get the error: "The constructor LinkedList(int) is undefined." When I remove the number, the code executes but nothing shows on the screen.

```
package practiceProject;

import java.util.*;

public class PracticeProject{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        List<Integer> list1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number");
        list1.add(userInput.nextInt());
        }


        for (Integer x: list1)
        System.out.print(x + " ");      

        userInput.close();
        }
}
```

How can I ask for user inputs and the print them on the screen using a LinkedList? Thanks!

Comment: What would be the purpose of `int` parameter in LinkedList constructor? Notice that *size* != *initial capacity*.

Comment: `list1.size()` is zero, so your first `for` loop does nothing.

Comment: I was just trying to set the length

Comment: Just a heads up @Ruben that `LinkedList` is dynamically sized. The `size()` method will simply tell you the number of elements in the list.

Comment: @arcadeblast77 So it's not like the length method with arrays right?

Comment: @Ruben That is correct. The `length`  field of an array tells you how long it is, which basically never changes. The `size()` method for `LinkedList` will tell you how many elements are in the list, which will change every time an element is added to or removed from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LinkedList` does not accept an `int` as params in any of its defined constructors.

You will need to define the number of inputs irrespective of the size of the `LinkedList`, perhaps with a separate variable.

```java
int numInputs = 5;
List<Integer> list1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
...
for (int i = 0; i < numInputs; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Ruben Always glad to help. Feel free to accept it as the official answer.